# Using modern AMD chips with Vmware and Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware, virtualization

Looking to build a cheap PC and then install VMWare workstation and Virtualbox to create some operating system virtual machines.

Do all modern chips work with VMware and Virtualbox, or do they need to be vt-x enabled chips?

Where can I find a resource that will tell me which of the chips int he link below are compatible with Vmware?
http://www.ebuyer.com/store/Components/cat/Processors-AMD?sort=price+ascending

Answer (score 0):

All x86 chips should work with both VMware & VirtualBox, but you'll need AMD-V (AMD name for hardware virtualization) to run 64 bit guest OS (it's possible to run it on Bochs or qemu, but far slower). For simplicity sake, you can just search the CPU series on [cpuboss](http://cpuboss.com/cpu/) since AMD own site isn't too easy to navigate.